# Ruby: Trying to Match / character

Tags: arrays, ruby, match

I'm trying to use the .match to recognize a single / (forward slash) character.

The line in question that is currently not working is:

```
elsif i.match([/[/]/]) then
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried mixing in \ (backward slash) but to no avail so far.

```
def calc(input)
    stack = []
    array1 = input.split(//)   #// splits into individual characters
    array1.each do |i|
        if i.match(/[0-9]/) then
            stack.push(i.to_i)
            puts "\n" ; print stack
            #array1.slice!(i.to_i)
            #array1.shift
            #array1.delete_at(i.to_i)
            #array1.delete(i)            
        elsif i.match(/[+]/) then
            result = stack[-2] + stack[-1]
            stack.pop
            stack.pop
            stack.push(result)
            puts "\n" ; print stack
            #puts "\n" ; print array1
        elsif i.match(/[-]/) then
            result = stack[-2] - stack[-1]
            stack.pop
            stack.pop
            stack.push(result)
            puts "\n" ; print stack
        elsif i.match(/[*]/) then
            result = stack[-2] * stack[-1]
            stack.pop
            stack.pop
            stack.push(result)
            puts "\n" ; print stack            
        elsif i.match([/[/]/]) then
            result = stack[-2].to_f / stack[-1].to_f
            stack.pop
            stack.pop
            stack.push(result)
            puts "\n" ; print stack        
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `then`, it's a bit of syntax nobody really uses. Likewise, avoid stacking multiple statements on one line for no reason using `;`.

Comment: One normally sees `input.chars` rather than `input.split(//)`, mainly, I think, because the former reads better. Regarding your question, `"/".match("/") #=> #<MatchData "/">` or `"/".match(/\//) #=> #<MatchData "/">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're breaking out your input into individual characters it's not necessary to use a regular expression to compare things. You can do straight-up comparisons like `x == '/'`. Given how many comparisons you're doing here, and they're all of a similar form, the structure you're actually looking for is to use a `case` statement:

```
def calc(input)
  stack = [ ]
  # Process individual characters in the string using `chars`
  input.chars.each do |c|
    case (c)
    when /[0-9]/
      stack << c.to_i
    when '+'
      a, b = stack.pop(2)
      stack << a + b
    when '-'
      a, b = stack.pop(2)
      stack << a - b
    when '*'
      a, b = stack.pop(2)
      stack << a * b
    when '/'
      a, b = stack.pop(2)
      stack << a / b
    end
  end
```

Note that Ruby's [`pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) method takes an optional argument for how many you want to pop. In your case you want two, so you can just ask for that.

Now you get this:

```
calc('23+4*')
# => 20
calc('82/')
# => 4
```

Now there's a lot of repetition in this code, so it can be boiled down to even less if you embrace Ruby's dynamic programming possibilities:

```
def calc(input)
  stack = [ ]
  input.chars.each do |c|
    case (c)
    when /[0-9]/
      stack << c.to_i
    when '+', '-', '*', '/'
      # Combine the last two entries using the method named by
      # the character.
      stack << stack.pop(2).reduce(c)
    end
  end

  stack[0]
end
```

In Ruby `a.send(:+, b)` is the same as `a+b` so you can often use tools like [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to apply an arbitrary operation on a set of things.

Comment: I started a comment then saw that you had already addressed it. Thought I removed it (as I've done now.) My apologies. Will delete this comment also.Good answer.

Comment: tadman this was extremely helpful.  Thank you!  My mind is getting a little blown by the number of operations ruby allows you to do in one line.    For example:  stack << stack.pop(2).reduce(c)    I'm amazed that that actually works and it seems out of order to my brain; I would think that you would need to go j = stack.pop(2); j.reduce(c); stack << j.  But you are able to do it all in just one and not get logical errors.  Amazing!

Comment: @BillBisco Method chaining is one of the core design features of Ruby. Being able to "pipe" the output of one into the next is what makes [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) so powerful: You can stack together a bunch of simple operations to create a complex one. In this case the right side of `<<` is a method argument so it's evaluated first, then applied. The code is, in effect: `stack.send(:<<, stack.pop(2).reduce(c))` which might look more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape `/` character. I would suggest to use `%r`.

And as you don't use the return value I would suggest to use `match?`.

```
'with /'.match?(%r{/})        #=> true
'without slash'.match?(%r{/}) #=> false
```

Another approach is `/\//`.

Note that you don't need `then` in `if-elsif-else`.

And I don't understand why you need regexps.

```
input.split(//) => input.split('')
i.match?(%r{/}) => i == '/'
```

Another thing -- you could consider using `case` statement.

Comment: Using `%r{/}`, where `%r{...}` is equivalent to `/.../` is not a bad plan.

Comment: Worth noting that `match('/')` and `include?('/')` are also options here since there's no actual regular expression in play and a string is fine.

Comment: Thanks Danil, this was helpful.  Ruby did not like /\// however.

Comment: Nobody's pointed this out in 4.5 years, but `i.match?(%r{/})` is *not* the same thing as `i == '/'`.